# How to add/remove focus marker to spec using vim script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vim

Do you know any plugin which helps me by using key mapping to add or remove focus marker: `focus: true` like below.

```
it "has added a feed item", focus: true do
  page[ cursor ].should have_css "#activities .feed-item"
end

it "shows question title in feed" do
  within ".feed-item" do
    page.should have_content "Where is wally"
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. Could you explain better what you mean by `spec` and what the code you posted is about?

Comment: What do you mean by "focus and unfocus"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to do something like `/, focus: true` then `d3E`. It's pretty easy to use the `:map` command to execute this sequence on a keypress: `:map <F2> /, focus: true<CR>d3E`

Comment: Thanks, but will be excellent to run it when cursor is not exactly after ``"`` but anywhere inside spec.

Comment: The search moves to the correct location. Replace the `/` with a `?` if you want to run it when the cursor is on the body. If you want it to work in either place, then that's a job for a proper function, which would require much more work.